# How to find a pictures properties?

Tags: lighting, photo-editing, color-correction

I took a picture and I really like the color and lighting in it so I was wondering if there is anyway to find out the properties, like the contrast/saturation/ tint etc, of it so I could replicate it in another picture maybe through editing.

Thank you

Comment: There are no such properties in a way you think.

Answer (score 1):

The settings that you're looking for don't really exist. I know that Canon's DSLRs allow for one to adjust the in-camera processing of JPGs using sliders for Sharpness, Color Tone, Contrast, and Saturation - and doing so would create an overall "look" to all photos taken with those settings...

But the big variable here is lighting.

You can't Photoshop the lighting you get from early morning sun, or a cloudy day, or high-noon, etc.

And even though a setting like Contrast can be adjusted - this doesn't help you to replicate the contrast-y lighting of high-noon sun vs a cloudy day.

There are different "looks" that can be done in post processing, but advising you on how to do it would necessitate you posting a photo from which to emulate.

Outside of that, the best that can be offered to your question is actually: the only way to achieve a photo with similar lighting to another is to match the light sources in the original.